# How correct do auto tagging of page break

Tags: errors, luatex, footnotes, compiling, expl3

In our package i want handle page break,to use tagpdf package in genericnode. For this i want to redefine \tagncbegin/\tagncend commands, to save last params of tagging. For this i save this params in tallest,but when i redefine \naketitle command,i get an error:

\inaccessible 
l.73 \maketitle

Also i have a problem with converting of tlist to keys,because according to documentation, in l3keys arguments consider as strings, so name of variables in arguments will consider as string value,but not as name of variable,which should be expanded. Help me please solve this problems. Thanks everybody very much for any help (i use the latest version of tagpdf  and pdfresources packages from newest )branches on GitHub and sorry for line separators,because i modified and write now my post from my Mac).

```
\RequirePackage[patches]{pdfresources}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{pdfversion=2.0}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tagpdf}
\tagpdfsetup{tabsorder=structure,uncompress,activate-all,add-new-tag=Title/P,interwordspace=true}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
  \tl_new:N \g__last_mc_tl %last opened mc tag with all params
  \bool_new:N \g__inside_new_page_command_bool
\let\orig@tagmcbegin=\tagmcbegin
  \let\orig@tagmcend=\tagmcend
\let\orig@newpage=\newpage
\renewcommand{\tagmcbegin}[1]{
\tl_gset:Nn  \g__last_mc_tl{#1}
\orig@tagmcbegin{#1}
}
\renewcommand{\tagmcend}{
\orig@tagmcend
\bool_if:NTF \g__inside_new_page_command_bool{}{\tl_gclear:N \g__last_mc_tl}
}
  \renewcommand{\newpage}{
  \tl_if_empty:NTF \g__last_mc_tl{
  \orig@newpage
}{
\bool_gset_true:N \g__inside_new_page_command_bool
\tagmcend
\bool_gset_false:N \g__inside_new_page_command_bool
\orig@newpage
\tagmcbegin{\g__last_mc_tl}
}}
%tagging of title

\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop
  {
    @author = H1 ,
    @date   = H1 ,
    @title  = H1 ,
  }
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[1]{\footnotemark
    \protected@xdef\@thanks{\@thanks
        \protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{\tagstructbegin{tag=H1}\tagmcbegin{tag=H1}#1\tagmcend\tagstructend}}
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \kozlovskiy_maketitle:
  {
    \tagstructbegin{tag=Title}
\prop_map_inline:Nn \l__kozlovskiy_data_of_title_prop{
\cs_set_eq:cc { orig@##1 } { ##1 }
\bool_if:nTF{\tl_if_empty_p:N {##1}}
{
\use:c { orig@##1 }
}
{
\cs_gset_protected:cpn { ##1 } {
\tagstructbegin{tag=##2}
\tagmcbegin{tag=##2}
\use:c { orig@##1 } 
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
}
}
}
\__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle:
    \tagstructend
  }
\cs_new_eq:NN \__kozlovskiy_original_maketitle: \maketitle
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \maketitle { \kozlovskiy_maketitle: }
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\tagstructbegin{tag=Document}
\author{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}
\title{test \thanks{Alexandr Kozlovskiy}}
\maketitle{}
\tagstructbegin{tag=P}
\tagmcbegin{tag=P}
Test
\newpage
test again
\tagmcend
\tagstructend
\tagstructend
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't redefine the tagpdf commands. Define your own commands if you want something else or some extension. Btw: the commands are defined with xparse, `\let` doesn't work with such commands to copy them, you need `\NewCommandCopy`.

Comment: and don't use variable names without module name like `\g__last_mc_tl`

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Now it happen something strange, because in \tagmcend command terminal freeses. Please,help me to fix this. https://pastebin.com/YgJrSMxh Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I will no help you to debug code where you redefine my commands.

Comment: @ulrike fischer Ok,but how i can insert eend of mc on a privious page and start of mc on the next page. Because,for example i have a problems with tables in Lua mode,but in the generic mode in large documents we have several pages. Ok,you will not helot debug my code. But please,only comment,whether i now did all correct in your opinion, and logical errors i will fix myself. Or i incorrect applied \NewCommandCopy?I haven't any idea, why in terminal i haven't any errors? May be it's some xparse issue? Because it seems for me,what i have infinit recursion, but how it appeared in my code? Thanks.

Comment: you can't do it. It needs changes in the output routine to get this right.

Comment: Ulrike Fischer do you mean, what i can not redefine \newpage command for my task or something else? Why lualatex process not stopped in terminal. What where wrong?

Comment: @ulrike fischer Can you please clarify,what you mean,when you wrote what i can not do it in the last your commentary?

Comment: an explicit \newpage is not so difficult, but you probably want also correct tagging for paragraphs which are broken over pages, and will only work after we changed the output routine.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer yes,in future i want to do tagging of paragraphs, but for now my example not works without tagging of paragraphs. I not understand,what happen,because i even can't close lualatex from terminal via control+d on my Mac. During of debug i noticed, what problem is in \tagmcbegin command, even without redefining of \newpage command. Why i can't redefine it normally? I do: \NewCommandCopy{\orig@tagmcbegin}{\tagmcbegin}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\tagmcbegin}{m}{
\tl_gset:Nn \g__last_mc_tl{#1}
\orig@tagmcbegin{#1}
}
Why it's impossible redefine it? It stop withsimple \orig@tagmcbegin.

Comment: You can't currently copy commands defined with xparse, the code isn't in latex yet. And you shouldn't do it with the tagpdf commands anyway.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer ok, why for \tagmcend i haven't this problem, but for \tagmcbegin i have this problem. Why for \tagmcbegin this problem happen? About output routine, how i can know,that you do it. May be you have issue on GitHub,on which i can subscribe,to know, when you will fix it? About not redefining tagpdf commands,How i can handle it using another way. As i understood,you haven't global property, which show for us latest opened mc tag and all it params.,such as: actualtext,alttext etc. So the one way to do it,it redefine tagpdf commands.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer If you will have property with all params,i will can save all params to new property,close mc tag,and open mc tag,using all params from new property. But now your package haven't this property i can't do anything without redefining of your commands. About impossibility copy xparse commands,why i haven't any errors in latex and why i haven't any recursion for redefining of \tagmcend command,but have problems for \tagmcbegin command. If it's not implemented yet,how i can do it for now? Or you mean,what it not implemented now copying xparse commands with several arguments? Thanks.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer So,how for now i can redefine document commands and why in commands without arguments i haven't infinit loop in lualatex?

Comment: As I wrote already: I will not help you to redefine the tagpdf commands. I'm quite happy that `\NewCommandCopy` doesn't work yet for them, if this prevents you from changing them. And you could do lots of other things, e.g. define your own tagging command instead of using \tagmcbegin.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Yes. It seems,i solved this problem,even for \maketitle.  For this i  used \cs_gset_eq+protected functions,instead of \let+\renew. Now,as i wrote before,it's exists not tagpdf problem, but l3keys problem. Your command  \tagmcbegin expected key_val list,but i insert convert name of token list (not list itself, but it's name),which cause l3keys error. So how to convert string value to key-value list?